# Noun-も+Noun-も+Noun-が construction?

Tags: grammar, anime

From: No Game No Life ep2, timestamp 04:35

Context: The character is explaining that they are basically broke.

> その代わり ささいな願いを聞いてくれ
>
> ぶっちゃけ俺らこれ使い果たすと宿も食い物も当てがなくなるんだわ

How does **宿も食い物も当てが**なくなる work, exactly?

AもBも is supposed to mean "Both A and B", but as far as I understand it's supposed to be followed by a predicate, and here it's followed by another noun instead. How come?

Does 宿も食い物も modify 当て or do all three nouns work as a unit to which が is attached? I'm confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've answered your own question here, you just haven't managed to figure out how your answer applies to the given text.

> AもBも is supposed to mean "Both A and B", but as far as I understand it's supposed to be followed by a predicate...

It *is* followed by a predicate. That predicate is `当てがなくなる`.
Basically you can parse it out like this:

> (宿も食い物も) (当てがなくなる)

Where the aforementioned predicate applies to both `宿` and `食い物`. A very direct translation might look something like this:

> 俺らこれ使い果たすと宿も食い物も当てがなくなる
>
> Once we use this up, we'll have nothing to rely on for both shelter and food.

`当て` is a little but awkward to translate into English, but hopefully this clarifies things. `having no options left for food and shelter` might be a more natural way to express the same thing.